# NSDate is 5 hours off

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I run the following code:

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

```
NSLog(@"now: %@", now);
```

and get :

2011-09-16 16:14:16.434 iSavemore[1229:7907] now: 2011-09-16 21:14:16 +0000

As you can see i'm running this at 16:14:16 (4:14 pm) but NSDate is returning 21:16:16 (9:14 pm!). Is this an Xcode4 issue or NSDate issue?

Comment: Is this on a device or in the simulator ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NSDate defaults to the Universal timezone (aka GMT).

I'm guessing you're somewhere on the East Coast, 5 hours behind UTC.

Try adding this to your date formatter...

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

...and you should see your local time.

If you want to use a specified locale, rather than 'currentLocale', create a NSLocale for the relevant locale.

```
NSLocale *usLoc = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];

[dateFormatter setLocale:usLoc];
```

...actually that's US (so possibly not Central).

More specific timezone help can be found here...

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

However, if you want to show expiry time, wouldn't you still want it in the user's currentLocale?

Comment: Im in the central time zone and i need to force NSDate to stay in central cause I have to calculate an expiration date and it'll be based out of Dallas no matter where the user is. How do i do that?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the output you'll see that the log includes the timezone:

```
2011-09-16 16:14:16.434 iSavemore[1229:7907] now: 2011-09-16 21:14:16 +0000
                                                                      ^^^^^^
```

The time stamp of your log is local time. I assume you're in a timezone that is 5 hours ahead of UTC.

A **NSDate** refers to a particular point in time. It's up to you to display this however you want; usually with an NSDateFormatter.

This is the reason why you'll see plenty of recommendations against storing a time, or a date as anything other than an NSDate. If you try and store it as a string you'll run into a lot of trouble later on when trying to handle the display in different timezones.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the time-zone of your NSDate to one that is fitting your need, for example `[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]`

Answer (score -1):

Just a wild guess here, but maybe it has something to do with time zones?