# How to create World Clock like application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I want to create iPhone embedded "World Clock" like application. At the moment I am able to create a single clock (analog clock) which can display Current device time.

Here, I am using

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

to retrieve the current Date/Time. Analog clock logic based on this NSDate object.

Problem is, **How can I get Date/Time of a Country (Australia, UK ...) on to this NSDate format?**

---------- and also, When I NSLog(@"%@", [NSDate date]); it gives Grin-witch time, Not the current Simulator time ---------

Comment: See this answer,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450510/nsdate-is-5-hours-off/7450544#7450544

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the time to whichever locale you need, see this answer for how to do that,

[NSDate is 5 hours off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450510/nsdate-is-5-hours-off/7450544#7450544)

Answer (score 0):

By using the `NSCalendar` & `NSTimeZone`, you can get the Date/Time, blew code snippet show how to get the current Date/Time in London.

```
let timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "BST")
let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let zoneComponents = calendar.componentsInTimeZone(self.timeZone, fromDate: NSDate())
hour = zoneComponents.hour
minute = zoneComponents.minute
second = zoneComponents.second
```

You can use this library called [SmileClock](https://github.com/liu044100/SmileClock) achieve all.